# Split datasets in categories, and count the datasets within these categories, in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, split

I have a menu. Every meal has a category like beef, pork, chicken, salad. Now I want to fetch every meal, split them according to the category and save them in an array. So that I have for every category an Array with meals. The last step would be counting the amount of meals in each category but this is easy when I am there.

My current attempt is very bad. I make a `mysql_query` with a filter for every single category and a second to count the datasets. So I have for one category two queries. If I have at the end like 30 categories, the server have to process 60 queries for one page view.

```
for($i=0; $i < $30; $i++)
{
    $fetchMeal="SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE Categorie = '$categorie[$i]'";
    $countMeals = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from Menu WHERE Categorie = '$categorie[$i]'");
}
```

I want only one to fetch all datasets, split them in categories and count the datasets within these categories. Does anyone know a good and easy way to accomplish this?

Example table:

```
name          | categorie
-----------------------
tomato-salad  | salads
potatotfish   | fish
peppersteak   | beef
schnitzel     | pork
ceasar-salad  | salad
another-fish  | fish
fish-fish     | fish
roast pork    | pork
```

etc...

now I want to have arrays for each category:

```
salads[0] -> tomato-salad
salads[1] -> ceasar-salas

fish[0] -> potatofish
fish[1] -> another-fish
fish[2] -> fish-fish

beef[0] -> peppersteak

pork[0] -> schnitzel
pork[1] -> roast pork
```

Comment: please read [**My Post**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) about how to properly ask a sql question... we need more info

Comment: Can a meal only belong to one category? If you have categories (chicken, salad), what does a chicken salad belong to?

Comment: no it cant. Every meal have only one category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is now that I order datasets by their categories. If I `echo` with the results it should look like this:

```
category | meal
---------+----------
fish     | cookes fish
fish     | potato-fish
fish     | fish-fish
fish     | another-fish
pork     | roast pork
pork     | schnitzel
beef     | peppersteak
salad    | tomato-salad
salad    | ceasar-salad 
salad    | another-salad
```

Then you have to find out how many categories you have. Because I have the name of the categories in another table I can count them with:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from categories");
$NumberOFCategories = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

When you don't have an extra table you have to make this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categorie FROM menu
```

and count your gotten datasets with a PHP `foreach` loop. Then I saved every dataset in an array with a `foreach` loop.

```
$i = 0 //counter
$menu = array();

while($tabellenInhalt = mysql_fetch_object($erg))
{
    $menu[$i][0]=$tabellenInhalt -> Category ;
    $mneu[$i][1]=$tabellenInhalt -> Meal;

    $i = $i+1; 
}
```

Now there comes the tricky part. You save the first category in a holder variable. And create a variable for a counter which you will need later in the `foreach` loop.

Then you make a for-loop which is as long as many categories you have (you got the Number at the beginning). After that you make a `foreach` loop through your array as long as your holder variable and the category are equal. I show you my code:

```
$m = 0; //counter for every dataset
$j = 0; //counter for the datasets in a category
$holder = $menu[$m][0]; //holds the actual/next category
$splittedMenu = array();

for($n = 0; $n < $NumberOfCategories; $n++) //Count three every company
{
        while($menu[$m][2] == $halter) //test if Category is still the same.
        {
            $splittedMenu [$n][$j][0] = $menu[$m][0];
            $splittedMenu [$n][$j][1] = $menu[$m][1];
            $m = $m + 1; //count threw all datasets
            $j = $j + 1; // count threw all datasets from one category.
        }
    $j = 0; //counter gets resetted when the next category gets called.
    $halter = $splittedMenu [$m][2]; //go to next category
}
```

Now your first dimension of you array separates the categories. The second dimension is for your meals and in the third you hold the different data (name of the category and the name of the meal).

Answer (score 1):

You need to `ORDER BY` your category. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM menu
ORDER BY categorie, name
```

You can then read these into a PHP array. Another way of doing it, to make it easy to group by the category, is to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categorie FROM menu
```

Then loop over the results and do this each time:

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE categorie = $categorie
```

Personally I'd do the first one, since you can grab the category and then just push items to an array thus:

```
$meals[$categorie][] = $name;
```

You mention that you are unhappy with 60 queries per page. In your case it is *is* inefficient, but 60 queries in itself is not necessarily a bad thing. Bear in mind that it is the total run-time that counts, not the number of queries. Sometimes breaking a problem down into several smaller queries can be quicker to execute than one large one.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer. Have to inform myself about these function a little bit more to understand because I am a beginner. Hope that works.

Comment: I think i understand know what to do. Your first method should work fine with a while-loop in another loop. thanks. have to test it tomorrow because its already 0:11 am here.

Comment: No probs, let me know how you get on. Incidentally, if you want to add more information to each category, it would be a good approach to split it into its own category. You would then join between `menu` and `category`.

Comment: ...split it into its own **table**, I meant `:)`.

Comment: could be an option, too but it is definitely not requiered

Comment: Got it. Thanks again for the help :) Will post my solution later.